# How can I represent state or environment in the $\lambda$-Calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I have seen in different tutorials how to represent numbers and booleans in the pure $\lambda$-Calculus, and  how to define some arithmetic and logic operations. But what if I want to represent other constructs, not usually encouraged in pure functional languages, like state (assignment of values to variables) and sequencing (evaluating $e_1$ before $e_2$)?

For example, how would I encode an assignment "$v := e$" (where $v$ is a variable and $e$ an environment)?  And what about encoding "$x := 2; y := y + x$"? (The point is that there is a dependency among statements, and they should be evaluated/executed in the correct order.)

Answer (score 4):

Such a thing is, for the most part, impossible in the pure lambda calculus: all variables represent immutable values.

However, you can fake it in a number of ways.

The simplest is parameter passing. For a function which has a "state", you give it an extra parameter, which is a data structure mapping variables to their values. Any time you alter a variables value, you just create a new store with the updated value, and use it as the new parameter.

This pattern of passing the state to each computation in sequence can be abstracted using a [State monad](https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad), or something similar. A state monad provides a pattern where the machinery of creating a new store, updating its values, and correctly passing it to future functions.

Monads provide a sequencing operator, which allow for the ordered evaluation that you mention.

There exists calculi which have mutation built into them, but first off, they aren't the *pure* calculus as you asked for, and in such cases, you don't encode mutation, you add it as a primitive operation.

Comment: The parameter passing way is interesting. Is there a "usual", or "standard" way of doing it using Church (or Scott) encoding? I don't remember having seen that as part of the usual treatment of this topic.

Comment: Usually, if you need something this detailed, you don't use a lambda calculus, you use a real language like Scheme or Haskell. But if you insist on using the LC, I would encode variable names as Church Numerals, and use Church Encoding to make pairs. You can encode linked-lists as pairs. Your store is then a list of pairs, with the first element the number representing a variable, and the second element its value.